# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.Conventions

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jsp

when i'm trying to run my project it's giving an exception in my jsp page.

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/com.amdocs.vPic] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/home.jsp] at line [144]

```
    141:                    </button>
    142:                </div>
    143: <div class="modal-body">
    144:                    <form:form action="LoginServlet" method="post"  >
    145:                        <div class="form-group">
    146:                            <form:label class="col-form-label" path = "uname">E-mail</form:label>
    147:                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" " path="email" required="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet needs a class which isn't part of your WAR or container's CLASSPATH. It's probably the spring jar file missing on your server's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding ***spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar*** to your classpath and also update it as a dependency if you haven't done so.